# What return statement can i use?

Tags: java, return

I don't understand why the error is no return statement.

```
public String[] Hop(String origin){
  int r;
  int c;
  if(Map[r][c]==1){
    System.out.print(cities[c]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything...

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language this is. (Java?)

Comment: What language are we talking about here?

Comment: From your question, one can readily presume that you don't need a return type for the method for what you wish to do. Did you copy this code from somewhere without understanding it?

Answer (score 3):

Your method's return type is `String[]`, so it is supposed to `return` a string array,and **there isn't any return statement inside your method body** that is why it is causing error. If you don't want to return anything then better change the return type  to **`void`**.